# Moving an Object on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, javascript-objects, keyevent

Currently im making a HTML5 Canvas Spaceship Game. But i've got a huge Problem: 
I created a Class for my Spaceship and i want to move it with the Arrow Keys. But for some Reason it won't move.

The Chrome Inspector won't show any errors but the Spaceship still wont move.

I'm not totally sure but could there be a Problem in the Object from the Class?

You can find the Project Data on my Git: https://github.com/nemoxdelight/First_Game/

Also, sorry for my bad English, i'm just a German who needs help ;)

Also here is the Part where i think the Problem could be: (in the main.js)

```
function o_move_paddle(p_event) {
    if(p_event.keyCode == KEY_RIGHT) {
        held1.rechtsTaste = true;
        p_event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(p_event.keyCode == KEY_LEFT) {
        held1.linksTaste = true;
        p_event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(p_event.keyCode == KEY_UP) {
        held1.hochTaste = true;
        p_event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(p_event.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) {
        held1.runterTaste = true;
        p_event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

And in the held.js where my Heroclass is created and it should move the Object:

```
Held.prototype.tasteCheck = function() {
    if(this.hochTaste) {
        this.held_y -= this.speed;
    }
    if(this.rechtsTaste) {
        this.held_x += this.speed;
    }
    if(this.linksTaste) {
        this.held_x -= this.speed;
    }
    if(this.runterTaste) {
        this.held_y += this.speed;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you (re)create your hero inside the main loop of your game.
So every time your game gets in the loop it makes a new hero at the begin coordinates. Therefor appearing not to move.

Here is a quick and dirty solution to your problem.
Inside your main.js change the 'loop' function so it is this

```
function loop(){
  clearCanvas();
  level();
  if(!held1)
    held1 = new Held();
  held1.draw();
  feinde_zeichnen();
  // snd.play();
}
```

You should create your hero elsewhere, before the loop is initiated, and only once so you can be sure it is always the some object.

EDIT:

Before i forget: you should reset the rechtsTaste,linksTaste,hochTaste and runterTaste variables of your held in the 'o_stop_paddle' function or it will keep moving once you let go of the key as well as stop moving all together once you pressed all directions as it will try to move in all directions, which equates to no movement at all.

Comment: Thank you @Pirokiko that really helped me a lot. But the Problem still exists after i changed the Code. I can move my Spaceship through the Console with `held1.held_x += 20;` Is there something i am missing? I also updatet my Git.

Comment: your console should also say something about being unable to find the Held class
Inside constant.js you now use `Held()` which it doesn't know yet, so include held.js before constant.js in you index.html
Also in main.js in `move_held` you move the held instead of setting rechtsTaste to `true`

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally worked for me! I now have a value that checks if the Loop is already running, and if so it doesn't draw it again. Could not me more Happy with the Solution :)